# How to set up no-www with AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, no-www

I own a site on AWS with Route 53. I want the site to be accessible without the `www` at the beginning, but am having trouble.

For the example the site name is `domain.com`. What I've attempted is creating an `A` record in the Record Set for my Route 53 site, with the name `domain.com` and target `www.domain.com`, in hope that this would let searching `domain.com` lead to `www.domain.com`. This didn't work, giving me an error for an invalid name value.

How do I get my AWS Route 53 domain to run without `www` at the beginning using the record sets in Route 53?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associate a A record or Alias with your top level domain name.

Just associate the same A record or Alias to your `www` record.

Here is an example from my domain :

```
stormacq.com.      A     Alias <my cloudfront distribution ID>
www.stormacq.com.  A     Alias <my cloudfront distribution ID>
```

```sh
$ dig stormacq.com +noall +answer

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> stormacq.com +noall +answer
;; global options: +cmd
stormacq.com.       44  IN  A   54.230.3.162
stormacq.com.       44  IN  A   54.230.3.70
stormacq.com.       44  IN  A   54.230.3.190
stormacq.com.       44  IN  A   54.230.3.146


$ dig www.stormacq.com +noall +answer

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> www.stormacq.com +noall +answer
;; global options: +cmd
www.stormacq.com.   60  IN  A   54.230.3.190
www.stormacq.com.   60  IN  A   54.230.3.70
www.stormacq.com.   60  IN  A   54.230.3.162
www.stormacq.com.   60  IN  A   54.230.3.146
```

Both names are defined in CloudFront Distribution configuration.  So, no redirection is needed, Cloudfront will happily serve both names.

Comment: Route 53 Alias vs non-Alias : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html

Comment: How to setup a Cloudfront distribution : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html

Comment: Name = www ; Value = the IP Address or CNAME or Cloudfront distribution you want to refer to.